# Draw gauge chart by Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I can draw gauge chart by canvas with function `arc()`. But, the shape is a half of circle.

Now, I'd like to draw gaugle chart like this (please ignore color or number).

[image]

How can I draw it? Thanks

UPDATE:

I draw the chart by drawing 2 arc (I don't use `ctx.lineWidth`)

```
var min=Math.PI*.60;
var max=Math.PI*2+Math.PI*.40;
var R = 100;
var arcWidth = 40;
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, R-arcWidth, max, min, true);
ctx.arc(100, 100, R, min, max);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b0nw4gma/

However, at position of `min` and `max`, chart is line instead of round. I tried to use `ctx.lineCap='round'`, but it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stroke an arc with a sweep-angle based on your desired gauge percentage.

[image]

In your example the 0% angle is (*estimating...*)

```
PI * 0.60
```

and your 100% angle is (*again estimating...*)

```
PI*2 + PI*.40
```

So your arc will always start at angle = PI*0.60.

Your arc will end at the angle calculated like this:

```
zeroAngle + (hundredAngle-zeroAngle) * guagePercentageValue
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var r=80;
var min=PI*.60;
var max=PI2+PI*.40;
var percent=50;

ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.font='24px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.fillStyle='gray';

$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:0,max:100}).val(50);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
  percent=parseInt($(this).val());
  drawGuage();
});

drawGuage();

function drawGuage(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  // draw full guage outline
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,min,max);
  ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
  ctx.lineWidth=15;
  ctx.stroke();
  // draw percent indicator
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,min,min+(max-min)*percent/100);
  ctx.strokeStyle='red';
  ctx.lineWidth=6;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillText(percent+'%',cx,cy);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=myslider type=range><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I update my question, how can I draw without using `ctx.lineWidth`. Thanks

Comment: @user4557573 Your update completely changes the possible answers to your question. :-(  Anyway, `lineCap` applies to the endpoints of lines. Your Fiddle creates a closed, filled path so `lineCap` does not apply. If you want the ends of your guage to be rounded instead of squared you can use `arc` or `arcTo`

Comment: I'm sorry bcz my question wasn't clear. Yes, your answer solved my original question :). I just want to draw gauge by another way. I still not got your idea, because I used `arc` already.

Comment: @user4557573 To clarify my comment ... You can use 4 arcs to create your round-capped guage. 2 arcs for the guage and 2 more arcs for the endcaps. Here's my comment turned into code: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2pnokex5/. Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: Thank for teaching me, markE. I didn't know the way to calculate the position of centers of 2 small arcs. With your code, everything is clear and done. Thanks again :)