# rotated partial doughnut chart with a point marker in chart.js agularJS

Tags: angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to create a partial doughnut chart (3/4 doughnut) using angular-chart.js. Is there anyway to do this?
In highcharts.js it is possible to specify the start and end angle (Say -135 to 135 (3/4 doughnut, rotated by -135 degrees) but in chart.js it not present it seems.

The doughnut chart in my case marks 3 regions, red blue green (on scale of 0 to 100) and I need to place a marker on the area (doughnut width is small and the point  marker covers the width). I need to place the marker at a point on the chart, say 76( on scale of 0 to 100) and stop the animation at 76.

Is this possible with chart.js? Can anyone share a fiddle?

Comment: Nope. ChartJS only does 360 degree donut charts. You can do it with native canvas as in [this previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508680/draw-gauge-chart-by-canvas/31509013#31509013)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can render partial doughnut/pie charts, but have you considered using a "blank" datapoint? This datapoint can be that remaining 1/4 value (blankData = 100 - (data1 + data2 + data3 + etc...)) You can set the coloring on it to be transparent or to match your page's background colors. In this way you can have what appears to be a 3/4 sized doughnut/pie chart.